# Sprites Spawning In Straight Away At The Start

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently making a game on Xcode 11, I am having a problem where in which my sprite will spawn in straight away at the start, even through their is a wait delay, but after the first spawn the sprites spawn in at their current time. How can I make it so the sprites wont spawn in untill 3 seconds after the scene has started. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The photo attached shows what happens at the start of the game.

[image: Ph]

I have attached part of my code for one of the sprites as their setup is similar to each other.

```
//Setup Bird
func setupBird() {
    bird = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bird-1")
    bird.name = "Bird"
    bird.zPosition = 20.0
    bird.setScale(1.5)
    let birdHeight = bird.frame.height
    let random = CGFloat.random(min: -birdHeight, max: birdHeight*2.0)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: cameraRect.maxX + bird.frame.width, y: size.height/2.0 + birdHeight + random)
    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.width/2.0)
    bird.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bird.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    bird.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
    bird.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    addChild(bird)
    bird.run(.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 15, withRange: 5), .removeFromParent()]))

    //Animation For Birds
    var textures: [SKTexture] = []
    for i in 1...3 {
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird-\(i)"))
    }

    bird.run(.repeatForever(.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.15)))

}
func spawnBird() {
    let random = CGFloat.random(min: 15.0, max: 30.0)
  run(.repeatForever(.sequence([
      .wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(random)),
      .run { [weak self] in
          self?.setupBird()
      }
  ])))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding frame.width/2.0 to the position, which moves the inital bird position.

```
bird.position = CGPoint(x: cameraRect.maxX + frame.width/2.0 + bird.frame.width, y: size.height/2.0 + birdHeight + random)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to spawn a bird periodically, starting after an initial delay.

You could delay the repeating action, either with another SpriteKit action or with DispatchQueue.

```swift
func spawnBirds() {
    let spawnBirdAfterDelayAction = SKAction.sequence([
        .wait(forDuration: 22.5, withRange: 7.5),
        .run { [weak self] in self?.setupBird() }
    ])

    run(
        .sequence([
            .wait(forDuration: 3), // initial delay
            .repeatForever(spawnBirdAfterDelayAction)
        ])
    )  
}
```

```swift
/// As Knight0fDragon pointed out, this approach is inferior because it circumvents the SpriteKit runtime.
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    self.spawnBirds()
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, I tried to add another SpriteKit Action, I copied your example but I still get the same results of the bird spawning in as soon as the scene starts.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `setupBird()`, can you see where the first call is coming from?

Comment: I added a break point, the only call for the function setupBird() is from spawnBird() and setupBird() and spawnBird() are both called on didMove function. But when I add a break point at the end of setupBird() it spawns at the same position and no more birds spawn, so I am thinking it might be a problem with setupBird() but I am not to sure where I need to fix it.

Comment: Do not use DispatchQueue with spritekit, the events will fire even if you leave the app.